# ConvertTo-Json in PowerShell output changes when object is nested one level deeper

Tags: powershell

Please note the output of the following block of code on PowerShell -

```
        $Attendees = @(
            @{
            "EmailAddress" = [pscustomobject]@{
                "Address" = "test1@abcd.com";
                "Name" = "test1";
             };
             "Type" = "Required";
            };
        );
        
        ConvertTo-Json $Attendees;
        $PSObject = @{ "Attendees" = $Attendees; };
        ConvertTo-Json $PSObject;
```

Output -

[image: Code snippet output]

Note how "EmailAddress" changes from object to a string. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: `ConvertTo-Json $Attendees -Depth 4`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen there isn't problem with `ConvertTo-Json $Attendees` (or, I don't see a problem here). Maybe `ConvertTo-Json $PSObject -Depth 4` intended?

Comment: Yes, I meant `ConvertTo-Json $PSObject -Depth 4`